# What does "within greater [region]" mean?

Tags: american-english

If someone says something such as "Within greater Seattle", what does that mean?

Comment: "Greater SomeCity" means the area including not only "SomeCIty" itself, but also all of its suburbs and contiguous towns.

Comment: The idea is sometimes rendered synonymously with the phrase "the Seattle [or wherever] metropolitan area."

Answer (score 2):

Seattle refers to the central, largest city. The surrounding region, which is often connected economically and culturally to Seattle. In other words, Seattle and its suburbs are the greater Seattle area.